# ASP.NET Core : asp-for using a string as input

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Would it be possible to dynamically create an asp-for on basis of a enum class?

```
@foreach (MyClass.MyOption item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyClass.MyOption)))
{
        var checkboxName = $"MyClass.CheckBox{item}";

        <label asp-for="@checkboxName" class="control-label">
            <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@checkboxName" class="radio-inline" value="true" name="@checkboxName" />
        </label><br/>
}
```

With these definitions of `MyRequest`:

```
public static class MyClass
{
    public enum MyOption : byte
    {
        First = 0,
        Second = 2,
        Third = 4
    }

    public class MyRequest
    {
        public bool CheckBoxFirst { get; set; }
        public bool CheckBoxSecond { get; set; }
        public bool CheckBoxThird { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I do so, I run into the error:

> InvalidOperationException: Unexpected expression result value 'MyClass.CheckBoxFirst' for asp-for. 'MyClass.CheckBoxFirst' cannot be parsed as a 'System.Boolean'.

Preferably it would also be my preference to even dynamically creating the bool functions in `MyRequest` (`CheckBoxFirst`, `CheckBoxSecond`, etc).

Tried with above code, but only the `asp-for` in the input type seems not to work, due to the parsing error.

Comment: asp-for is always expecting a boolean parameter when input type is checkbox, or a string parameter that can be parsed as boolean. Why not only use  `name="@checkboxName" ` ? It works fine.

Comment: Thank you for your reaction @QingGuo. "@CheckBoxName" is a function which returns/set a bool, right?

Comment: That will solve he error: for asp-for. 'MyClass.CheckBoxFirst' cannot be parsed as a 'System.Boolean'. But you will get the name and id =checkboxName, not the result you want.

Comment: So your suggestion is to just do: '''<input type="checkbox" class="radio-inline" value="true" name="@checkboxName" />''', right?

Comment: Yes, you can use `name` and `id` to replace the `asp-for`.

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding. But how will it then bind to the MyRequest booleans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how will it then bind to the MyRequest booleans?

1. use `name="@checkboxName"`

2.change the `checkboxName` into  `$"MyRequest.CheckBox{item}"`

Try the below code:

```
<form  asp-action="Index" method="post">
    @foreach (MyClass.MyOption item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyClass.MyOption)))
{
        var checkboxName = $"MyRequest.CheckBox{item}";

        <label name="@checkboxName" id="@checkboxName" class="control-label">
        
        </label><br/>
         <input type="checkbox"  class="radio-inline" value="true" name="@checkboxName" id="@checkboxName"/>
}
<input  type="submit"  value="create"/>
</form>
```

DynamicaspforController:

```
public class DynamicaspforController : Controller
    {
     
        public IActionResult Index()
        { return View(); }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index( MyRequest myRequest)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

result:

[image]